# Carthage Code Sign Error

Tags: ios, carthage

I've cloned [this iOS application](https://github.com/JakeLin/SwiftWeather/issues) from github and tried running [carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) with `carthage update` as outlined in the documentation. However when I do, I get an error stating (in fact, this is my whole terminal output):

```
Deans-MacBook-Air:SwiftWeather deang$ carthage update
*** Fetching SwiftyJSON
*** Fetching Alamofire
*** Checking out Alamofire at "1.3.1"
*** Checking out SwiftyJSON at "2.2.1"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/p0/chbxzj8920v2gwrqfcnb8p380000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.fdWo4D.log
*** Building scheme "Alamofire OSX" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "Alamofire iOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “(null)” were found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Framework' in SDK 'iOS 8.4'
A shell task failed with exit code 65:
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)

Deans-MacBook-Air:SwiftWeather deang$
```

And the `Cartfile` looks like this:

```
github "Alamofire/Alamofire"
github "SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON"
```

Now I don't know if this is specific to the project (though I don't think so, it's quite a popular one and no one else seems to be complaining). So I'm inclined to think it's something I'm doing wrong or something that's wrong with my environment.

Comment: Okay it looks like it's because you need a paid developer account. Which I don't have. Though I'd delete this but perhaps this might be useful for other people in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build/install the App without paying on Xcode 7, just login in your Apple ID into Xcode.